# Both outer and inner divs have ng-click and when I click on the inner div, both ng-clicks execute. How to prevent that?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 divs, an outer and inner one that have ng-click attached to both of them. When I try to click the inner div, both functions execute ( I assume because I'm essentially also clicking the outer div because it contains the inner one ). How can I prevent the outer div's function from executing when clicking on the inner div?

```
<div ng-click="vm.showMorePosts()">
    <div ng-click="vm.actionHandler($event, action)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to keep it from bubbling up

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.showMoreHandler = function(e) {
      console.log('showMoreHandler');
    }
    $scope.actionHandler = function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log('actionHandler');
    }

  }]);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-click="showMoreHandler($event)">showMoreHandler
    <div ng-click="actionHandler($event)">actionHandler</div>
  </div>
</div>
```